# What format is the Google Picker API auth token?

Tags: firebase, oauth-2.0, google-api, jwt, google-oauth

If I intercept an `access_token` from an example on this page:

https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/

...it looks like this:

`ya29.Glx7BW_OsFJ1CSjJ_kdt9iZixJAZHjvllMtJO09EccpURJPbCXudNP6teBz6HZ0T_ioaQLNna323UPpBQN-N0aCLWXfDVCvq4xXkbi5kKQhfwS0xakcsrNmzD5B8OA`

If I paste that into here:

https://jwt.io/

...I'm told it's malformed. However, if I paste a Firebase auth token into there, it's well-formed and you can see its payload.

Ultimately, I'm trying to use the Firebase auth token in the Google Picker API, but I can't figure out how to translate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using `firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken`, but it looks like `firebase.auth().getRedirectResult()` gets an auth token that is the same format as the Picker API.

Answer (score 0):

Google API access is scope based https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes

You must specify the scopes needed when requesting an access token.

Each access token you receive back, is limited to the scope and application from its original request. They are not inter-changeable.

You will need to setup a specific Google Picker API request, in order to get the access token you require https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2

Hope this helps

Comment: Firebase lets you add scopes when you log in, so you should be able to use the resulting oauth token to authenticate other Google APIs.

Answer (score 0):

"ya29.*" token is Google's access token and it is not a jwt (it is opaque for the api callers). 
Yes firebase allows you to add scopes during the sign-in process. After that you get an id token that says who the user is and a separate access token that you can use to access Google APIs. 
If you look at https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin you will see this:

```
 Then, you can also retrieve the Google provider's OAuth token by calling getRedirectResult when your page loads:
firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then(function(result) {
  if (result.credential) {
    // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
    var token = result.credential.accessToken;
    // ...
  }
  // The signed-in user info.
  var user = result.user;
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems the only way to get the Oauth token is manually logging people in. I'm using the Firebase-UI Web auth flow.